# Is there a way to set stroke behind shape

Tags: android, shapes, stroke

When I add stroke as shown below it is always half inside a shape and half outside. I want it to be only outside (or behind the shape), because I'm using semitransparent stroke and it's ugly when it covers shape. Sorry about my English, I hope you understand what I meant and what I want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset android:inset="16.0dip"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="10.0dip" />
            <solid android:color="?android:colorBackground" />
            <stroke android:width="18dp" android:color="#40ffffff" />
        </shape>
</inset>
```

Comment: Can you show images?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7L5jctQbDY8S0R4b2xDbndnUjg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layer two different shapes using a `layer-list`.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="10dip" />
            <stroke android:width="18dp" android:color="#40ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:top="8dip"
        android:right="8dip"
        android:bottom="8dip"
        android:left="8dip">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="10dip" />
            <solid android:color="?android:colorBackground" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```